Struggling with OpenProject Setup: Docker vs. Deb Packages
I've been trying to set up OpenProject for my organization, but I've been encountering issues for a week now. I've attempted to run it in Docker containers and through Deb packages, following the OpenProject documentation thoroughly.
https://www.openproject.org/docs/installation-and-operations/installation/docker/
However, I'm unable to configure it properly. Initially, I tried Docker Compose and Stack, but encountered errors. Then, I set up another VM and tried installing it via Deb Packages.
https://www.openproject.org/docs/installation-and-operations/installation/packaged/ Although I managed to configure OpenProject, accessing it through the web browser was unsuccessful. I then attempted an all-in-one container setup, but encountered a different issue when running the container interactively -it flag with the command:
docker run -it -p 8080:80 \
-e OPENPROJECT_SECRET_KEY_BASE=secret \
-e OPENPROJECT_HOST__NAME=localhost:8080 \
-e OPENPROJECT_HTTPS=false \
-e OPENPROJECT_DEFAULT__LANGUAGE=en \
openproject/community:13

This setup worked perfectly, but I prefer not to run it interactively. So, I tried running the Docker container with the -d flag using the command:
docker run -d -p 8080:80 \
-e OPENPROJECT_SECRET_KEY_BASE=secret \
-e OPENPROJECT_HOST__NAME=localhost:8080 \
-e OPENPROJECT_HTTPS=false \
openproject/community:13

However, this didn't work, even though I'm using the same image. Can someone please guide me on the correct method to install and configure OpenProject?
